# Find an isomorphism between an open subset of $\mathbb{A}^1_\mathbb{C}$ and $V(x^2+y^2-1)\subset\mathbb{A}^2_\mathbb{C}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-geometry, affine-varieties

> Find an isomorphism between an open subset of $\mathbb{A}^1_\mathbb{C}$ and $V(x^2+y^2-1)\subset\mathbb{A}^2_\mathbb{C}$.

As an excercise, I am asked to find an isomorphism as in the question. This may be  a very trivial example but i did not come across it, and have never really solved such excercises.

Obviously $V(x^2+y^2-1)\subset\mathbb{A}^2_\mathbb{C}$ is the unit circle in $\mathbb{C}^2$ as an affine variety. Moreover I know that the nonempty open sets of the Zariski topology on $\mathbb{A}^1_\mathbb{C}$ are $\mathbb{A}^1_\mathbb{C}$ itself and the cofinite sets. Hence I am trying to find a morphism between $\mathbb{S}^1$ and such sets. The fact is that I do not know many projections, apart from the stereographic one which I think won't do in this case since it excludes the "point at infinity"

Morever I know that distinguished open subsets of a variety $X$ in  $\mathbb{A}^n_\mathbb{C}$ are always isomorphic to a "canonical" hyperbola-like variety $Y$ in $\mathbb{A}^{n+1}_\mathbb{C}$, but cannot figure out how make the isomorphism work with $Y=\mathbb{S}^1$.

Thanks for hints or help.

Comment: For pedagogical reasons I'd like to point out that no subscheme of $\mathbb{A}^2$ is "bounded". You should not think of your variety as the unit circle at all! $\mathbb{S}^1$ is the set of real points of your variety which is very much not what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $x^2+y^2 = (x+iy)(x-iy) = z\cdot z^{-1}$

Comment: Thanks, sadly I fear I am getting a bit confused here with the representation of $\mathbb{C}$ as $\mathbb{R}^2$, and its notation. Let us call $X=V(x^2+y^2-1)$, are you suggesting to send the _couple_ of complex numbers $(z_1,z_2)\in X\mapsto (z_1+iz_2)\in\mathbb{A}^1=\mathbb{C}$? This would have image in $\{z\in\mathbb{C}|z=z_1+iz_2\ and\ z^{-1}=(z_1-iz_2)\; z_1,z_2\in\mathbb{C}\}$ ... but I am missing why this is open in $\mathbb{A}^1_\mathbb{C}$

Comment: Theres an isomorphism of rings $\mathbb{C}[z,z^{-1}] \to \mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2 -1)$ which sends $z\mapsto x+iy$, you can take its dual to get a map of varieties

Comment: And yes the map of varieties is $(x,y) \mapsto x+iy$ as you said, with the inverse $z\mapsto ( (z+1/z)/2, (z-1/z)/2i )$. Perhaps one confusing part is $|x+iy|^2 \neq x^2 +y^2$ because $x,y$ are complex parameters, not the “usual” real ones.

Comment: Thanks! But your approach is indeed neater